# Android - Applying TextStyle "bold" removes custom font setting

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I'm experiencing strange issue.

Currently I have a `TextView` using my style

```
<TextView
    style="@style/MyText"
    ... />
```

and in `styles.xml`,

```
<style name="MyText" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/noto_sans_kr</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/noto_sans_kr</item>
</style>
```

and lastly, this is my `noto_sans.kr.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:font="@font/noto_sans_cjk_kr_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        app:font="@font/noto_sans_cjk_kr_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

This works perfectly fine. I see my custom font, and even when custom font is used by system, it only uses the font I set in my app.

However, weird thing happens when I apply `android:textStyle` attribute to the `TextView`.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/MyText"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    ... />
```

gives me correct design preview from Android Studio, but as soon as I start the app, the `TextView` is using the system font I set, not the noto sans.

Now, if I don't use `textStyle` and just use noto_sans_bold font file directly, it works perfectly fine.

```
<TextView
    fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_cjk_kr_bold"
    ... />
```

Is this the font file's metadata problem? or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use font-family and text style attribute together in your XML file

```
<TextView
    fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_cjk_kr_bold"
    android:textstyle="bold"
    ... />
```

Comment: Why tho? The font already has 700 weight, so it’s a bold font.